# Proving a triangle with different edge colors exists in a graph.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This is again some homework translated (hopefully not too badly) from my book

The graph $K_{n}$ is colored using $n$ different colors, in a way that each color is used at least once. Prove that there exists a triangle with its edges colored in different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the smallest cycle $C$ in your graph with all edges distinct colors. We know $C$ must exist, because there are $n$ colors (I'll let you think about why). If $C \neq C_3$, consider a chord of $C$. The chord divides $C$ into two smaller cycles. One of these cycles should provide a contradiction to the minimality of $C$.

Comment: Ah yes, this is a bit more efficient than my answer!

Comment: Hi, I think I understand your approach. I have a question though: Is it generally a fair assumption to make if I say that a graph with $n$ edges over $n$ vertices has a cycle? Also, is it possible to go your way but assuming by contradiction that a triangle does not exist, and then choosing the smallest distinctly-colored cycle and contradicting the minimality? Or preheps this is exactly what you did and I didnt understand well. Thank you.

Comment: @BorisAblamunits Yes, you are correct, any graph on $n$ vertices with $n$ edges must have a cycle. Remember that acyclic graphs are forests, and each tree in a forest has $v-1$ edges, where $v$ is the number of vertices in that tree. So the number of edges in a forest on $n$ vertices is $n - c$, where $c$ is the number of connected components in the forest. Thus a graph on $n$ vertices and $n$ edges cannot be a forest, and must have a cycle.

Comment: @BorisAblamunits And yes, assuming there is no $C_3$ with distinct colors for contradiction will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following simpler case (and use it as a lemma for your problem). Suppose you have a cycle $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ where each edge is coloured differently (so with $k$ colors out of the $n$). Now draw "chords" from $v_1$ to $v_3,\ldots,v_{k-1}$, and color these edges using any of the $n$ colors. This gives you $n-2$ triangles. Show that one of these triangles must have all edges colored differently.